# saving multiple values from one changing TextView using shared preferences?

Tags: java, android

I have one textView value that the can be changed using a plus and minus button. (like androids number picker object but custom.)

I need to be able to extract each value and save if depending on a spinner value that is set by the user.

For each value that is saved for each spinner position, when the user returns to the same position on the spinner, the previous value entered will appear indicating a value has already been entered.

For Instance:(If spinner is the day of the week)(value is the TextView/custom Spinner) "If the user selects Wednesday, and picks a value of 7, then goes to Monday and picks 8, if the user returns to Wednesday the value entered before (7) will show, if the user returns to Monday the value 8 will show.

#### Spinner code

```
final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_dotw);
final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =    
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.dotw_array, R.layout.custom_spinner);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        spinner1position = position;
        spinnerPos();
        showToast("spinnerdotw: position= " + position + "id=" + id);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        showToast("No Dotw selected");
    }
});
```

#### Number picker code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String getString = String.valueOf(tvSony.getText());
    int current1 = Integer.parseInt(getString);

    if (v == btnUp1) {
        if (current1 < nEnd) {
            current1++;
            tvSony.setText(String.valueOf(current1));
        }
    }

    if (v == btnDown1) {
        if (current1 > nStart) {
            current1--;
            tvSony.setText(String.valueOf(current1));
        }
    }

    sonyRs = current1;
}
```

#### Any Suggestions on how to do this would be highly appreciated ?

#### My Attempt So far:

```
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("sun32save", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor spedit = sp.edit();

    if (spinner1position == 0 & spinner2position == 0) {

        spedit.putString("sun32Son", String.valueOf(sonyRs));


        String savedValue1 = sp.getString("sun32Son", "");
        spedit.commit();

        tvSony.setText(savedValue1);

    }


            //if a value is found, display value
    if (spinner1position == 0 & spinner2position == 1) {

        spedit.putString("sun35Son", String.valueOf(sonyRs));


        String savedValue2 = sp.getString("sun35Son", "");
        spedit.commit();

        tvSony.setText(savedValue2);
```

This returns the default value 0 if i go back to the same spinner position.

#### Screenshot

[image: UI]

#### Edit Error

```
06-01 18:37:51.503  18264-18264/com.example.liam.quickreport20 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.liam.quickreport20, PID: 18264
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.liam.quickreport20/com.example.liam.quickreport20.UnitsForm}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object com.example.liam.quickreport20.UnitsForm$Cache.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object com.example.liam.quickreport20.UnitsForm$Cache.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.liam.quickreport20.UnitsForm.loadTextFields(UnitsForm.java:220)
        at com.example.liam.quickreport20.UnitsForm.onCreate(UnitsForm.java:152)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
```

Comment: Hello, there's something missing. Can you finish your question, please?

Comment: Yeh sorry I thought i had made some progress on this but, it turns out the code i used was useless. The question is still open for suggestion

Comment: Eugen, would you happen to have a suggestion ?

Comment: You can use `SparseIntArray` to map e.g. 1 (monday) to 8 in memory. If you need to store it to disk (`SharedPreferences`) you can use Gson to store/receive said sparse array to/from shared prefs as a JSON string. That's just off the top of my head, there's probably going to be a more effective way. This is the lazy way.

Comment: haha it's probably allot better than what I was trying to do.

Comment: tried another method, works until you continually go back and forth between both spinner positions and eventually the values are the same I guess its because there both reading and saving from the same textview Any sugggestions to fix this ?

Comment: 1) `sp` and `sp2` are the same thing. 2) You have a value, I suspect `sonyRs`. You put it to SP, you read it from SP. Why so complicated, when you already have it?

Comment: Thanks, true just changed it there. .Yeh sonRs is the value I'm trying to store. The problem i'm having is because I'm using the same TextView output value for both spinner positions, they both always set to the same value. Would you happen to know a fix ?

Comment: I'm more of a visual person. Attach a screenshot and I'll think of something. In the meantime grab a pen and paper and check the connections and callbacks between all these widgets if you've missed something important, I'll be doing the same.

Comment: Screenshot has been added. I hope this helps. I will do Thanks

Comment: So if I selected Sunday, 0735 (is that time?) and set 5,4,3,2 and then changed Sunday to Monday OR 0735 to something else, everything would reset to zeros. And when I'd change the spinners back, the numbers would come back as well. Is that correct?

Comment: (0735 is a sales planning group) I've only been saving the Sony value atm, But yes it works in that sense. If I try and set a value for Sony on Sunday, then go to Monday and set a value for sony, that's when things get messy.

Comment: Any luck with it ? I'm lost

Comment: Take a look at this. https://gist.github.com/consp1racy/c92d4cf4734a267b8f10 I tried to recreate the activity, it is clunky but it works, and hopefully you'll get the idea how to piece it together. Sorry I wasn't able to provide a traditional answer.

Comment: Your a legend, I'll give it a try. Thanks for all your help !

Comment: Sorry, what api package is Cache in it doesn't seam to exist in my project ?

Comment: Cache is a nested class inside my activity, scroll to the end of `MainActivity.java`. It's just a shortcut for `HashMap<something>` because top-level generics are a pain in the ass with Gson.

Comment: Ahh I see now, didn't even notice that.Thanks

Comment: appreciate the help allot, would you be able to post layout screen shot just for reference ?

Comment: Check the gist again there was an error in `loadTextFields` resulting in NPE + I added row layout XML. Here's the screenshot http://send-picture.com/img-556cd7399dfb8.html

Comment: I've added the logcat error I get ?

Comment: *There is a new couple of lines in `SpinnerActivity#getPersistedData` (not `loadTextFields`, sorry) to avoid this.

Comment: I added the new lines and it appears to still give me the same error

Comment: My bad, once more the same spot. The same null-check belongs both in `savedInstanceState` condition and `getPersistedData` method. The problem was that `gson.fromJson(null)` returns null and doesn't throw exception.

Comment: Works like a dream. Thankyou so much.

Comment: How would I retrieve the values individually if I want to use the saved ones ?